# How can I show modal on page load?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, qweb, odoo-16

I have a page with a modal window. I can show and hide this modal with a button and the right data-bs- attributes.

Now, What I want is to have the modal shown on page load. It seems the only proper way to do it is to get the modal element in JS and call its .show() method.

But I don't know how to do it on a qweb-only template. Is there a way ?

```
<template id="my_template" name="Hello there">
    <t t-call="portal.portal_layout">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="my_modal">
            Show Modal
        </button>
        
        <!-- I want this modal to pop up on page load as weel as being able to toggle it with my button -->
        <div id="my_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="my_modal_title">Hi</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn text-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-close"/></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Content ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not a problem to [introduce scripts with Qweb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68302656/1264804) (or simply include it in your markup). I see no reason to deviate from best practice using [Bootstrap's methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-javascript). Doing so should result in basically this (note the embedded script located after the Bootstrap library link):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal'));
myModal.show();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My point of departure was https://jsfiddle.net/saptamdev/rhfkpvow/11/

My changes:

- I added a CSS so we will have a background and `display: block;` will not be inline
- I added the `show` class to `modal fade`
- I added `onclick` attributes to handle the clicks. The modal will appear on page load without these onclick attributes as well, but for the sake of this example I preferred to make it more functional
- I added an id to the modal to make sure my CSS rule is applied to it and only it

```css
#exampleModal.show {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade show" onclick="$(this).hide();" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @isherwood thanks for clarifying the reasons for your downvote. To answer your first question, the reason is that this Bootstrap version was used in the fiddle that I used as my point of departure. No ill intent was involved. As about your second question, I'm not really a Bootstrap user, so I was not inclined by default to run bootstrap functions.

Comment: @isherwood a "point of departure" is the point where the thinking process/experimentation was started. I searched for a Bootstrap example, found the one I have shared in my answer and made it load.

Comment: @isherwood I believe I already mentioned that I'm not really a Bootstrap user, which is the cause of me not needing the usual practices there. If you dislike the code in my answer, then any suggestion is more than welcome. I guess one of the problems was that I did not call the `hide()` function. So I edited my answer to make that improvement. However, if you request further improvements, then I'm afraid you will need to be more explicit about them. Anyways, thank you for your comments.

Comment: @isherwood I've given an example where the popup is shown on load. The same ideas should work if applied to the original popup inside the question. But stackoverflow is not able to preview qweb templates as far as I know, so this was the reason I used another structure as the point of departure. I guessed that anyone reading my answer will understand what I'm suggesting to the structure inside the question, especially since I have explicitly described the changes.

Comment: @isherwood so if you would prefer me to use the original structure,  then someone will need to convert it into a format that properly runs inside a snippet. I was willing to help by answering the question and showing how this can be done, but I'm not motivated to work on the qweb template into something that works inside a snippet. So, if you do that, let me know and I will apply the idea for that then.

Comment: @isherwood I was not aware of what Bootstrap versions there are. Now that you mentioned it, I applied Bootstrap 5. Thanks for the time you have invested into discussing this.

Comment: @isherwood adjusted the link and the script accordingly. Thanks!